# STOP the tableview , arrays, labels, from reset data automatically in TodayWidget extension?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm using xcode 7 swift 2

in my app extension(TodayWidget extension) i'v put 2 table views that store the calculating results.......
[2 TableViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TWgw.png)

and its work fine, even if i scroll TodayWidget/notification view UP and DOWN again the data is there

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiY3i.png)

BUT sometimes after i scroll TodayWidget/notification view UP and DOWN again all data is lost and reset values to 0 again !!???

how i can prevent that from happening .....!!!

Comment: Please don't add tags to your questions titles (the tags section is there for that). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table view have to reset the data in table view cells automatically. that's how it works. while scrolling, as soon as the cell becomes invisible it will be taked to be reused for other indexpath. 
To achieve what you want in quite simple. You just need to have a dataSource to save your data in so you will not lose it while scrolling.

If you share some of your code I'll be able to give you more details how to solve this problem.